# How to create hollow geometries with holes in Three.js (without CSG.js?)

Tags: javascript, three.js, csg, threecsg

I'd like to create a hollow box with some holes in Three.js.

Currently I managed to create a hollow box by creating a regular geometry and pushing triangles by hand (I created the inner box and than the outer box and merged the two together).

What I would like to know is if there's a simper solution that would also allow me to create holes in the cube.

Now, I've done some research on this question and found out about [CSG.js](http://evanw.github.io/csg.js/). While this library looks like it would be a perfect fit for my needs, I'm not so comfortable with incorporating it into my codebase as it wasn't updated in more than 4 years (last commit was done on the 20th of August, 2012.

So my question is - is there a (practical) way to achieve what I want without using CSG.js?

Also, if you have any way to address my concerns about CSG.js I would appreciate it very much.

P.S.: I would like to be able to control the shape of the hole as well - but for simplicity sake let's say I'm talking about diamond-shaped (Rhombus) holes.